# Отсутствие расширения у файла в адресной строке

Tags: .htaccess, файлы, php

Как сиё осуществить?  
Вк такая схема, к примеру `vk.com/feed`
расширение у `feed` отсутствует, и сервер не пишет `404`.
Возможно необходимо изменить `.htaccess`?

Comment: [Вики:ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_(%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да вы правы это .htaccess, почитайте про "mod rewrite" в интернете куча информации, ну и для примера:

```
RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ file.php?data=$1
      RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ file.php?data=$1
```

Этот код в .htaccess будет перекидывать: **mysite.ru/demo** в **mysite.ru/file.php?data=demo**

Таким образом всё управление закладываете в file.php и выводите нужный контент в зависимости от GET переменной $data. Удачи.

Comment: Благодарю!